# How to check if journaling is enabled on any partition

Tags: filesystem, ext4

i need to know which partitions have has_journal flag enabled

i know i can run

```
tune2fs -l /dev/block/sda1 | grep features
```

is there a way i can check all partitions in `/dev/block*` and only list those that have has_journal flag?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple for loop:

```
for d in /dev/block/*; do
  [[ $(tune2fs -l ${d} 2>/dev/null | grep -c has_journal) -gt 0 ]] && echo ${d}
done
```

This will loop through all items in /dev/block.  It will run tune2fs -l on it and pipe the output to grep.  If the output has has_journal in it anywhere, it is considered a match.  If there is a match, it will print out the /dev/block filename.

You can expand on this to convert the /dev/block name into the actual filesystem path, mount point, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ShadyPaz, You may need to run this with elevated permissions, `sudo`, because of `tune2fs`